# Execute Multiple Clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I am trying to click a button multiple times. Each time the button is clicked, it loads for 1 second, reappears and is able to be clicked again. I want to click this button 5 times.

```
 for(i=0;i<5;i++) 
  $('.class').click();
```

The above code only executes one click.

Even this code, **execute only one click.**

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++) 
 setTimeout(() => $('.class').click(),2000);
```

If I do the step manually , that is if I enter $('.class').click() to the console five times, it works. Any idea as to why ?

Comment: Why are you setting up a listener in a loop. You only need to attach a listener to a element on the DOM once, once it gets attached to it, it will work as many times as you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply the delay with the `i` since for loop does not wait for executing the **[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)** callback.

```
for(i = 1;i <= 5; i++) 
  setTimeout(() => $('.class').click(),i * 2000);
```

---

Another way is to use **[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)** method along with **[`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)**.

```
// variable for count
var i = 0;
// reference for clearing interval
var inter = setInterval(()=>{
   // trigger click event
   $('.class').click(); 
   // increment and check value reached to `5`
   // if `5` then clear the interval
   if(++i == 5) clearInterval(inter);
},2000);
```

Comment: That one worked... Can you please tell me why i* 2000 is required?

Comment: @RetroCode : otherwise all of the  get executed after `2000` milli second

Comment: that was quite the gotcha

Comment: How would you do it with setInterval() ?

Comment: @RetroCode : added in the answer

Comment: for some reason if I replace the forloop with a while($('.class').length)  everything freezes.

Comment: I don't think so because the button disappears after 5 clicks. hmmm

Comment: @RetroCode : `$('.class)` selects element even it's hidden :) so the statement would be always true and which leads to infinite loop.... change it to `while($('.class:visible').length)`

Comment: @RetroCode :  although while method does not wait for the execution of the callback

Comment: Seems to be freezing still :S ,do you think the reason is that while doesn't wait for callback ? How would you do it without while ?

Comment: @RetroCode :  use `setInterval` and inside callback check the condition and clear the interval

Answer (score 0):

If you log the click event on button, it is clicked 5 times, even with your first example

```js
$('.button').on('click', function () {
 console.log('clicked')
})

for(i=0;i<5;i++) 
  $('.button').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button"></button>
```